# Unable to Boot from USB External Hard Drive

Tags: windows-xp, usb, boot, external-hard-drive

I recently upgraded my main development machine to Windows 7.  This involved wiping out my primary boot drive (Windows XP 64-bit) and starting clean.  Before I wiped it, I did a direct disk-to-disk copy to a big external hard drive I have.  While I have been able to migrate most of the necessary files without any problems, I was wanting to boot from it today to check a few settings.  I plugged in the hard drive, rebooted, changed the BIOS to boot from USB-HDD first.  But, no mattter what I do, it always boots from my primary drive to Windows 7.  I do not see any kind of error message or anything.

How can I boot to Windows XP 64-bit on this external hard drive?

Comment: I am currently running a `CHKDSK /R` on this drive right now.  But it is a 2TB so it may take a while.

Answer (score 1):

Is the external drive bootable? How did you copy the data?

You need a boot sector on the drive, generally laid down by the installation process.

A simple windows copy will not copy this sector. You'd need to do the equivalent of a unix "dd" command to grab the exact image of the disk.

Comment: I used Norton Ghost to do the disk-to-disk copy

Comment: Is there any way to make it bootable?

Comment: I *think* Ghost is supposed to do this, but am not sure. If you completely disconnect the internal drive and try to boot from the external drive, what happens?

Comment: I will have to try that later, I am on the road now.  Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way may help you.

[Guide: How To Create A USB Bootable Installer Drive For Windows 8](http://www.techtree.com/content/features/1596/how-to-create-a-usb-bootable-installer-drive-for-windows-8.html#.UVLCWVdZOvg)

## finally i found the answer!!

I needed to boot from a External Hdd, because I had no CD/DVD-drive and no flash usb. This worked for me:
Use MiniTool Partition Wizard, a free tool!

```
- create a boot disk in partition wizard
- boot your computer with boot disk in
- copy the win8-iso-partition (do the step 5 thing as well, but as described in comments) from external hdd to the computer hard drive.
- set partition as primary and active
- reboot, and boot from local drive
```

Step 5: In the Command Prompt, type-in the following commands and hit Enter key after typing each command.

```
x:

cd/boot

bootsect x:
```

(where “x” is your external hard drive’s drive letter)

Answer (score 0):

I have booted off USB drives many times. Some disk copy software does not copy the boot sector. Use the command on the Windows 7 DVD in the BOOT menu - bootsect.exe /nt60 x: (where x: is your external drive)

Comment: not working :( i have this problem too